# Setting a default domain when using windwos authentication in web app

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

I have a MVC web application I wrote for an internal application at our company. We are using "Windows Authentication" as the authentication method for conencting to it and using it. I was wondering if there was a way to allow users to only type the username, and not need the domain name. Kind of how it works if you are on the network, and try to connect using I.E. Cna I place a default domain name in the web.config section, or no? I have seen that all examples are using the domain and username for the settings under allow, not saying everyone in the domain.  Thanks in advance.

```
<authorization>
      <allow roles="IDS\TaxFormerUpdate, IDS\TaxFormerView"/>
</authorization>
```

I need something like the following:

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="IDS\TaxFormerUpdate, IDS\TaxFormerView"/>
  <allow users="IDS\*" />
</authorization>
```

Thanks in avance

Comment: You could get the current domain of the user if they reside on the domain. Afterwards, you could just use the current domain.

Comment: Can you show me an example if possible? Do you mean, in the code behind? Wouldn't that not help though with using domain\username in web.config settings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161246/get-domain-name