# Obtain domain name and suffix

Tags: c#

The following name returns machine.domain.suffix, e.g. mymachine.mydomain.local

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName("LocalHost").HostName;
```

I would like to obtain only 'mydomain.local' (to target a dfs namespace).

Is there a cleaner way than using substring?

Comment: It might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161246/get-domain-name

Comment: Well, the name is hierarchical - only you know which parts have a meaning to you.

Comment: The `HostName` is a string with a predictable format.  How isn't using a substring "clean" enough for you?

Comment: @KarthikAMR That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @rory.ap Well there are multiple ways to skin a cat, and I'd rather rely on a component to do it for me rather than string manipulating. IMO better code: System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161246/get-domain-name)  `System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;`